# decode json to List[A] in scala with Argonaut

Tags: scala, argonaut

I have a type Wf which is

```
case class Wf(id: Option[WfId], socId: SocId, year: Int, employment: Float) extends WithId[WfId]
```

I have the following implicit function defining an argonaut decoder

```
implicit def WfDecodeJson: DecodeJson[Wf] = {
  DB.withSession {
    implicit session: Session =>
      DecodeJson(c => for {
        id <- (c --\ "id").as[Option[WfId]]
        socCode <- (c --\ "soc").as[Int]
        year <- c.--\("predictedEmployment").\\.--\("year").as[Int]
        employment <- c.--\("predictedEmployment").\\.--\("employment").as[Float]
      } yield Wf(None,
          SocSchema.socsTable.filter(_.code === 2216).first.id.get,
          year,
          employment))
  }
}
```

here is the json I am trying to decode

```
{
soc: 2216,
predictedEmployment: [
{
year: 2014,
employment: 19916.416015625
},
{
year: 2015,
employment: 20252.84375
},
{
year: 2016,
employment: 20345.037109375
},
{
year: 2017,
employment: 20640.29296875
},
{
year: 2018,
employment: 21200.6328125
},
{
year: 2019,
employment: 21564.833984375
},
{
year: 2020,
employment: 21896.298828125
},
{
year: 2021,
employment: 22376.546875
},
{
year: 2022,
employment: 22867.8828125
}
]
}
```

if I do

```
json.decodeOption[Wf]
```

I get the expected some(Wf)

if I do

```
json.decodeOption[List[Wf]]
```

I get Nil.  If I add breakpoints to the implicit decoder it enters the for comprehension when i just ask for Wf.  It dosn't even seem to enter the for comprehension when I ask for the List[Wf]

if I do

```
json.decodeValidation[List[Wf]]
```

I get

```
Failure([A]List[A]: [])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Better to look at the details of failure (hidden when using `decodeOption`)

Comment: thanks, thats listed at the end

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON starts with `{`, not `[`, so it's not an array which could be parsed as `List[T]`.

Comment: So do you have any advice on how I can parse it given that I need that soc parameter that is outside the array in each of the objects created from the array?

Comment: Review your decoder to make it accept a root object as the JSON.

Comment: Thanks I understand what you are saying about the { vs [ thing and it makes sense but I cant find anywhere in the docs where it talks about this.  sorry for being dense I just dont know enough to dig in and be able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing the DecodeJson instances manually by hand using the cursors you'd be much better off using methods like casecodec2 and friends.GeneratedDecodeJsons

Comment: Thanks they are definitely easier to write it seems but it still dosn't fix my problem above.  I have changed to caseCodec4 for Wf and caseCodec1 for WfId and I still get nil when using decodeOption(List[Wf]) on the above json

Comment: and actually when I just do decodeOption[Wf] with the new methods I get None instead of the one some I was getting using the cursors